# Transpose SOAP XML rows into columns in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

I've been working on a script that I want to transpose the following SOAP xml response elements from row to columns, but I have not been successful in finding the correct solution for this. I am using **PowerShell 5.1.1**.

Here are the XML elements to support the question's evidence:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Body>
  <deviceListResponse xmlns="http://SERVERURL.domain/">
   <return>
    <items>
     <first>device.deviceid</first>
     <second>123456789</second>
     <key>device.deviceid</key>
     <value>123456789</value>
    </items>
    <items>
     <first>device.uri</first>
     <second>127.0.0.1</second>
     <key>device.uri</key>
     <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </items>
    <items>
     <first>device.longname</first>
     <second>DESKTOP-123ABC456</second>
     <key>device.longname</key>
     <value>DESKTOP-123ABC456</value>
    </items>
    ...
   </return>
  </deviceListResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I use a Invoke-WebRequest to HTTP POST to get device information via the `-Body` parameter. The body is considered the following:

```
$body = @"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ei2="http://SERVERURL.domain/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ei2:deviceList>
         <ei2:username>example@domain.com</ei2:username>
         <ei2:password>$($env:password)</ei2:password>
         <ei2:settings>
            <ei2:key>customerID</ei2:key>
            <ei2:value>123456</ei2:value>
         </ei2:settings>
      </ei2:deviceList>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@
```

How can I make to something presentable so that I can use it in a `PSCustomObject` methods?

Edit 1: I do have the XML variable declared when using the Invoke-WebRequest method.

Comment: Did something in my answer turn out not to work as intended? If so, please provide feedback; quietly unaccepting will not resolve the issue.

Comment: @mklement0 I added some more details in the question after realizing I left out a critical detail that I was supposed to disclose. I do apologize for that if I wasn't clear enough to present the question in a more detailed way.

Comment: I've looked at your update, but it didn't make it any clearer for me. How do IDs come into play? Generally, please don't expand the scope of your question or change your requirements after answers have been given, as that may invalidate the latter and can certainly lead to confusion. Instead, please ask a _new_ question focused on the expanded / changed requirements.

Comment: Reverted back to the original version and I am going to post a new question with the updated requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following transforms the `<items>` elements in your web-service response into properties of a single `[pscustomobject]` instance, using:

- [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) to extract the elements of interest
- combined with a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call that builds up a(n ordered) [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) from the child elements of interest
- which is converted to a `[pscustomobject]` instance afterwards:

```sh
# Simplified sample response from the web service.
$xmlText = @'
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Body>
  <deviceListResponse xmlns="http://SERVERURL.domain/">
   <return>
    <items>
     <first>device.deviceid</first>
     <second>123456789</second>
     <key>device.deviceid</key>
     <value>123456789</value>
    </items>
    <items>
     <first>device.uri</first>
     <second>127.0.0.1</second>
     <key>device.uri</key>
     <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </items>
    <items>
     <first>device.longname</first>
     <second>DESKTOP-123ABC456</second>
     <key>device.longname</key>
     <value>DESKTOP-123ABC456</value>
    </items>
   </return>
  </deviceListResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'@

# Initialize the ordered hashtable that will collect the key-value pairs
# from the XML
$oht = [ordered] @{}

# Loop over all <items> elements and add their <key> and <value>
# child elements as key-value pairs to the output hashtable.
Select-Xml -Content $xmlText //ns:items -Namespace @{ ns = 'http://SERVERURL.domain/'} |
  ForEach-Object {
    $oht[$_.Node.key] = $_.Node.value
  }

# If necessary, convert the ordered hashtable to a customobject.
$customObj = [pscustomobject] $oht
```

The above yields the following `[pscustomobject]` instance in `$customObj`:

```
device.deviceid device.uri device.longname
--------------- ---------- ---------------
123456789       127.0.0.1  DESKTOP-123ABC456
```