# Transpose iterative SOAP XML rows into columns in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

In a follow-up post of [my original SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572100/transpose-soap-xml-rows-into-columns-in-powershell), I would like to be able to iterate key-value pairs from a `result` item set that goes down like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Body>
  <deviceListResponse xmlns="http://SERVERURL.domain/">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
   <return>
    <items>
     <first>device.deviceid</first>
     <second>123456789</second>
     <key>device.deviceid</key>
     <value>123456789</value>
    </items>
    <items>
     <first>device.uri</first>
     <second>127.0.0.1</second>
     <key>device.uri</key>
     <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </items>
   <items>
    <first>device.longname</first>
    <second>DESKTOP-123ABC456</second>
    <key>device.longname</key>
    <value>DESKTOP-123ABC456</value>
   </items>
  </return>
 <!-- Item 2 --> 
  <return>
   <items>
    <first>device.deviceid</first>
    <second>123456789</second>
    <key>device.deviceid</key>
    <value>123456789</value>
   </items>
 <items>
  <first>device.uri</first>
  <second>127.0.0.1</second>
  <key>device.uri</key>
  <value>127.0.0.1</value>
 </items>
 <items>
  <first>device.longname</first>
  <second>DESKTOP-Bus</second>
  <key>device.longname</key>
  <value>DESKTOP-Bus</value>
  </items>
 </return>
 </deviceListResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I achieve this in a PowerShell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided to the previous question against this new document? The XPath selector used in mklement0's answer (`//ns:items`) should work just fine in this case too.

Comment: I did. However, the variable assigns the last return object value instead of giving me the complete array of the hashtable items (such as `DESKTOP-123ABC456` and `DESKTOP-Bus` values in the `device.longname` array variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a relatively small tweak is required to the [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67572609/45375):

```sh
# Assume that $xmlText contains the XML text to parse.

# Initialize the ordered hashtable that will collect the key-value pairs
# from the XML.
$oht = [ordered] @{}

Select-Xml -Content $xmlText //ns:items -Namespace @{ ns = 'http://SERVERURL.domain/'} |
  ForEach-Object {
    # See if an entry already exists for the key at hand.
    if ($oht.Contains($_.Node.key)) {
      # Convert the entry value into an array on demand and 
      # append the value at hand.
      [array] $oht[$_.Node.key] += $_.Node.value
    }
    else {
      # Create the entry, using the value as-is.
      $oht[$_.Node.key] = $_.Node.value
    }
  }

$customObj = [pscustomobject] $oht

$customObj # output
```

The above yields the following `[pscustomobject]` instance in `$customObj`:

```
device.deviceid        device.uri             device.longname
---------------        ----------             ---------------
{123456789, 123456789} {127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1} {DESKTOP-123ABC456, DESKTOP-Bus}
```

Note that the `{ ... }` enclosure is just the PowerShell output-formatting system's (perhaps confusing) way of signaling that a value is a *collection* (array).